# Dotnetexe to Windows universal app

Tags: win-universal-app, exe

Is there any way to take a dotnetexe app and make it with any way a Windows universal app? I can do anything, just to make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of your need. If you want to convert the .net code to create a full uwp project, you have to perform this job manually. So, by the way, answer is **no**.

But, if the goal is just to use the Windows Store to deploy your .NET application. You have now a solution named Project Centennial. This solution just package your .exe/.msi to an .appx.

[Project Centennial": Converting your Classic Windows App (Win32, .Net, COM) to a Universal Windows App for Distribution in the Windows Store](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-692)

[Desktop App Converter Preview (Project Centennial)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51691)

Comment: Project Centennial is all I needed! Thanks!